# Max width for each column in jquery datatable

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatable

**Table**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
       <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="border-collapse: 
       collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Sr. No.</th>
               <th>Product</th>
               <th>Status Description</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>Product 1</td>
               <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            ....
         </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to reduce the width of *Product* column, it should be of fixed size and should not increase if length of data in it increases.

I have tried using **width="20%"** in th but it only affects the default width.
I have also tried:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

but it also changes the default width but increases if longer data is inserted in td.

Also the data in Status Description is appearing in one line which sometimes goes out of the page how can I keep that fixed so that data is displayed in multiple lines.

My goal is to reduce the width of Product column so Status Description column could be displayed in the same line as Product.

Comment: I use inline css in `<th>` like `style="width: 10px;"` and works for me

Comment: @Vpa Does not make difference in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to remove **nowrap** from the class so data is displayed in multiple lines and if you want to remove +/- remove **dt-responsive** and add **table-layout:fixed** in style tag of table and specify width for each column.

Answer (score 0):

[image: datatables image]

Works for me, I think your datatables is the reason.. because you're using expand row (maybe)